# MySQL SELECT query dies without output an error

Tags: php, mysql, execution-time

I'm doing a simple select query (`select * from metadata order by fecha_ingesta desc`) and I'm having troubles because server returns me a 500 status error but nothing is output in response tab of Firebug.

I'm pretty sure that the error has something to do with execution time because if I add a limit to the query the server returns a 200 status and database info is correctly displayed (`select * from metadata order by fecha_ingesta desc limit 6400`).

What perplexes me is that I have the flag `max_execution_time` and `set_time_limit` from php.ini set to 0.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: btw, are you using error checking at all in your query? hard to say which API you're using here, so I can't give you all the links for those. what about error reporting and anything in your logs? also, if you made any changes to the .ini file(s), did you restart all services?

Comment: You may also have a default limit of  300 seconds on Apache or IIS configuration ! And memory limits on php.ini ...

Comment: @BeS According to the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#timeout) the Apache `TimeOut` directive probably doesn't apply to PHP scripts (unless, I'm guessing, you're using mod_cgi or mod_proxy).

Comment: @IcarKwon 500 error is just a generic error code. As Fred said above, you need to check your error logs or turn on error reporting to see what is actually happening. Don't try to guess what's wrong. Get PHP to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Could you please paste the whole code for the page which is returning the error?